# Skewed NDVI values

Tags: python, rasterio, ndvi

I'm analyzing open-source NIR images with Python. I'm a novice to remote-sensing and have a doubt about my NDVI results.

I calculate my NDVI like so:

```py
    with rasterio.open(self.tif_path) as src:
        # Read bands 4 (NIR) and 1 (Red)
        nir = self.rescale_image_array(src.read(4)).astype(float)
        red = self.rescale_image_array(src.read(1)).astype(float)

        # Calculate NDVI
        ndvi = np.true_divide((nir - red), (nir + red))

        print("Minimum NDVI:", np.min(ndvi))
        print("Maximum NDVI:", np.max(ndvi))
```

This is giving me values from -1 to 1 as expected.

However, the visual of the NDVI shows almost exclusively positive NDVI values, although the picture contains streets, buildings and water, which should have low NDVI values according to what I read about NDVI...

[image: water,]

[image]

As can be seen, streets and buildings have values of around 0 (white) and only the water surface have slightly negative values (blue).

Does this indicate that I did something wrong during the processing or is this a result that can be expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite normal. In many situations the NDVI doesn't go far below 0. This is why often the color palette will be chosen that everything below 0 is water, rather than putting water (blue) at value -1.